# Why does the official Elasticsearch documentation use term query in the boosting query example?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been studying Elasticsearch recently and came across the boosting query in the official Elasticsearch documentation. In the example provided, the term query is used for both the positive and negative fields. Here is the example from the documentation:

```
"query":{
"boosting":{
  "positive":{
    "term": {
      "text": "apple"
    }
  },
  "negative": {
    "term": {
      "text": "pie tart fruit crumble tree"
    }
  },
  "negative_boost": 0.5
}
```

I'm confused as to why term query is used here, especially for the negative field where there are multiple words. My understanding is that term query does an exact match, and it seems improbable that the text field would exactly match "pie tart fruit crumble tree".

Wouldn't it make more sense to use a match query in this case, given that it analyzes the query string and handles multiple words? I feel like I might be missing something or misunderstanding how term queries work.

Can anyone explain why the term query is used in this example and in what scenario this would be appropriate?

Thank you in advance!